# Bubble plot with facets displays data only for one facet instead of all

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below

```
GO<-c("cytosol (GO:0005829)","cytosol (GO:0005829)")
FE<-c(2.70,4.38)
FDR<-c(0.00159,0.00857)
Facet<-c("ileum 24h","ileum 72h")
CCC<-data.frame(GO,FE,FDR,Facet)
```

and with this code

```
CCC %>%
  arrange(desc(CCC$GO))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FDR, y=GO, size=FE, color=FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(0,8), name="Fold enrichment")+ facet_grid(cols = vars(Facet))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  )+
  scale_y_discrete(name="GO biological process complete")+
  scale_x_discrete(name ="FDR")+
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value = NA,name="FDR")+ theme_bw()
```

I create the bubble plot below. The issue is that I should have had a bubble in both facets but now only one is displayed.

[image]

Comment: The x axis is continuous and you're using `scale_x_discrete`. Try changing to `scale_x_continuous`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* plotted points in both facets. It's just that you have told ggplot that you want the sizes to vary between 0 and 8 by setting `scale_size(range = c(0, 8))`. Since there are only two levels of the variable `FE` to map to the size scale, this means that the lower value is mapped to size 0 and the higher value is mapped to size 8.

So the simple fix is to either get rid of the size scale and just make the points the same size by setting `geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 8)` or change the `range` parameter in `scale_size` so that the smallest value is actually visible.

```r
CCC %>%
  arrange(desc(CCC$GO))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FDR, y = GO, size = FE, color = FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 8), name = "Fold enrichment") + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Facet), scales = "free") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "GO biological process complete") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "FDR") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name  = "FDR") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]